# Prevent copy of all resources after incremental build when filtering of resources is enabled

Tags: eclipse, maven, m2eclipse

Whenever `filtering` is set to `true` in a maven pom, each incremental build will copy all resources to the target folder. This can take some time or even cause side effects as these files get a new modify date.

```
<build>
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
            <filtering>true</filtering>
        </resource>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/test/resources</directory>
            <filtering>true</filtering>
        </resource>
    </resources>
</build>
```

Is it possible to disable this?

Comment: What exactly is the problem? If the time is modified? About how many files are we talking about?

Comment: Doesn't really matter how many files it is in my case. All files are copied. Every time I save. This can't be intended.